# Do I have to raise or bet after going all in pre flop?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, all-in

So I go all in preflop, after post flop when it is my turn, unable to check because there is a bet from previous player, does that mean I still have to call or raise?

Answer (score 1):

since you are already go all in, you dont get to action until the showdown.

Answer (score 0):

No. Folding to action is always an option. Besides, if you're all in what are you going to bet with?